# typescript class decorator: typing properties defined in decorator function

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, decorator, typeof

bar is a simple class decorator that adds a property to the class Foo.

```
function bar(target) {
    target.inDecorator = 'in decorator';
}

@bar
class Foo {
    inClass:string;
    inDecorator:string;
    constructor() {
        this.inClass = 'a string';
    }

    getInClass() {
        return this.inClass;
    }
}

console.log(Foo.inDecorator);
console.log(Foo.prototype.inDecorator);
const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.getInClass());
console.log(foo.inDecorator);
```

The only console log that causes an error is the first, Foo.inDecorator, the inclusion of which in ts 1.5.3 gives

```
Property 'inDecorator' does not exist on type 'typeof Foo'.
```

As far as I can tell inDecorator should be defined on the prototype of Class Foo and should be available on Foo as if it were a static prop. Running the resulting js file reveals undefined for the prototype access as well as on the new foo object, however Foo.inDecorator prints correctly even though it is the source of the error. To be more clear, we get

```
in decorator
undefined
a string
undefined
```

Any ideas on how to correctly type/add a static prop or method?

Thanks!

Edited this as I originally overlooked the fact that prototype access, Foo.prototype.inDecorator was not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the decorator `target` refers to the function—`Foo`—rather than the prototype—`Foo.prototype`.

So in the decorator doing `target.inDecorator = ...` is the same as `Foo.inDecorator = ...` and not `Foo.prototype.inDecorator = ...`.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
interface BarStatic {
    new(): BarInstance;
    inDecorator: string;
}

interface BarInstance {
    inDecorator: string;
}

function bar(target: BarStatic) {
    target.inDecorator = 'static';
    // note that prototype will be `any` here though
    target.prototype.inDecorator = 'instance';
}

@bar
class Foo {
    static inDecorator: string; // required
    inDecorator: string;        // required
    inClass: string;

    constructor() {
        this.inClass = 'a string';
    }

    getInClass() {
        return this.inClass;
    }
}

console.log(Foo.inDecorator);           // static
console.log(Foo.prototype.inDecorator); // instance
const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.getInClass());          // a string
console.log(foo.inDecorator);           // instance
```

Comment: this definitely works, but it seems like a lot of excess code and certainly isn't intuitive. why does inDecorator have to be on a base class if it is the same as Foo.inDecorator? If one were to add a static prop directly on Foo with static newProp = "new string", would it also have to be typed in this strange way? No way to implement an interface instead of extending a class? Or using static inDecorator: string; on the Foo class instead? My own experiments point to no. Thanks for the working solution though! I just hope that typescript has a more concise method

Comment: Awesome! thanks for working this out! in the case of simply adding a prop from the decorator, I guess it does boil down to    static inDecorator: string;     right in Foo, if you're not typing to interfaces or adding to prototype. I swear I tried that. :) Classical inheritance is much cleaner here, but I'm trying to write out an angular 1.x that looks and feels like 2.0 using component and view decorators to do a good deal of the directive logic. A bit silly perhaps. Those functions also do a lot of other more decorator specific work, just couldn't seem to get typing the prop in ts. Thanks!